# detect form submit() without multiple event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a web app which I'm trying to make run as fast as possible, one of the ways is by reducing the amount of event listeners I have attached.

I have a lot of forms (around 12). I currently check if they are submitted with:

```
$('#form-id').on('submit', function(){
    //actions here
});
```

for each form. Is there a way I can do this but with only attaching one listener for a submit? and then doing a switch statement based on the forms ID to decide what actions to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use delegation for `submit` event for all selected forms. `$(this)` will be the current form.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function () {  
   // actions here
   // $(this).something...
   return false;
});
```

`return false` is used to prevent the default browser behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Use event delegation

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ....
});
```

This adds just one listener to the document which gets called anytime a form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
   //you can use  $(this).attr('id') to get id of submitted form
}
```

to catch submit event for all form.

Comment: does this only add one listener though? or a listener for each match for the selector?